# Let $G=AB$; $A,B,G$ $D_{\pi}$-groups; $A_1,B_1,G_1$ Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $A, B, G$ resp. Show that exist $x,y$ such that $A_1^x,B_1^y \leq G_1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to solve an exercise about $D_{\pi}$-groups. Firstly, a finite group is a $D_{\pi}$-group if every $\pi$-subgroup is contained
in a Hall $\pi$-subgroup and any two Hall $\pi$-subgroups are conjugate.

The problem is the following: We have a finite group $G=AB$ product of its subgroups $A$ and $B$, with $G$,$A$,$B$ all $D_{\pi}$-groups for a set $\pi$ of primes. Taken $A_1$, $B_1$ and $G_1$ Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $A$, $B$, and $G$ respectively, we want to show that exist elements $x$ and $y$ such that $A_1^x$ and $B_1^y$ are both contained in $G_1$.

I reasoned as follows. Since $A$ is a $D_{\pi}$-group, if $A_2$ is another Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $A$, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ have to be conjugate in $A$. So $A_2=A_1^x$ for some $x \in A$. In the same way, if $B_2$ is another Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $B$, we have $B_2=B_1^y$ for some $y \in B$. Now $A_1^x$ and $B_1^y$ are $\pi$-subgroups of $G$, so they have to be contained in some Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.

But why are they contained in exactly the same $G_1$?

Comment: This follows from the fact that all Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate.

Comment: So, it's like $A_1^x \leq G_3$, $B_1^y \leq G_2$ with $G_3, G_2$ Hall $\pi$-subgroups of G. Then we have $G_2= G_3^g$ for some $g \in G$. If i call $G_1=G_3 ^g$, it follows that  $A_1^x \leq G_3 \leq G_3^g= G_1$ and $B_1^y \leq G_1$. It is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A_1$ is a $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ so contained in a conjugate of $G_1$, say $A_1 \subseteq G_1^x$. Then $A_1^{x^{-1}} \subseteq G_1$. Do the same for $B_1$. Can you finish?

Note that you do not need $G=AB$ at this point. If so, I think one can prove that a Hall $\pi$-subgroup $G_2$ of $G$ exists, with $G_2=(G_2 \cap A)(G_2 \cap B)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it's a simple way than mine. So we have $A_1^{x^{-1}} \subseteq G_1$ and $B_1^{y^{-1}} \subseteq G_1$. If I rename $x_1=x^{-1}$ and $y_1= y^{-1}$, I've found $x_1$ and $y_1 \in G$ such that $A_1^{x_1}$ and $B_1^{y_1}$ are both contained in $G_1$.